# IDE recommendations for EV3 programming

Tags: ev3, programming

Does anybody have any recommendations for non-GUI programming of the EV3 unit?

I'm impressed by the LabVIEW software, but as a professional C# and VB.Net programmer (with C, C++ experience), I find it slow and difficult to implement complex mathematical formula.

In particular, I love the ability of LabVIEW to transfer and run (and effectively debug) programs directly into the block with BlueTooth, so an IDE with that capability would be ideal.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are a C# pro, I would recommend [MonoBrick](http://www.monobrick.dk/). I know they have a plugin for Xamarin Studio/MonoDevelop that lets you do remote debugging. Not sure if they have one for Visual Studio yet.

There is also [EV3Basic](https://github.com/c0pperdragon/EV3Basic), which is an IDE that lets you program the EV3 using the BASIC programming language. Unlike most other 3rd party programming languages this one actually uses the official EV3 firmware.

Comment: Thanks - looks interesting... I'll investigate when I get a spare moment, which unfortunately won't be any time soon.  Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: Maybe I should have looked at the website a bit earlier - didn't realise you needed a spare SD card (which, despite being professional IT, I don't actually have)... oh well, will have to wait a bit longer

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an [Eclipse CDT (C/C++) plugin](http://c4ev3.github.io) which lets you create projects and compile/upload/download them. Check it out!

The EV3 has a gdbserver running on it, so you can connect to it from Eclipse. The plugin doesn't automate that however. (Maybe you feel like fixing that? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I made an IDE available on a simple wibsite at the following address:

http://jasvap.somee.com ( use this to see a screenshot )

If the above link doens't work you can download it from my OneDrive disk (preferable):

http://1drv.ms/1yJi3cp (use this to download the program )

Please read the README.txt file that will appear when you open the program!!!

Hope you enjoy it,

Steven Persyn

Answer (score 0):

Mac users, I worked on [Robotary](https://robotaryapp.com), a Swift-based IDE for programming both the NXT and EV3.

It has compiler-driven code completions, syntax highlighting, an LLDB-based debugger, Bluetooth and USB support, various examples, documentation, and various tools (file manager, screen mirror, etc.).

Comment: link looks broken...

Answer (score 0):

I like the [EV3 Swift playground for iPad](https://www.apple.com/swift/playgrounds/). It's not 100% feature complete but does the job.